# calendar created dynamically losing styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a calendar being created dynamically when you click an date-field input.  I have set up a set-interval function that will look for certain classes that are present in this calendar so that I can wrap elements to style.  When you click previous or next month however, new HTML is generated and my styles do not update.

Here is my set interval function that wraps the elements in div's:

```
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('.ui-datepicker-header').length) {
            var $set = $('#ui-datepicker-div').children();
            for(var i=0; i<$set.length; i+=2){
                $set.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="calendar-wrap"></div>');
            }
            var $prev = $('.ui-datepicker-header').children();
            for(var i=0, h=$prev.length-1; i<h; i+=2){
                $prev.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll('<div class="prev-next-buttons"></div>');
            }
            console.log("Exists!");
            clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
    }, 100);
```

Since I am adding `calendar-wrap` to the whole thing, I set up another function, to trigger an click event to start the set-interval again so the style's will update:

```
    $(".calendar-wrap").on("click", function(){
        checkExist();
    })
```

This is not working however, so I was wondering if there is a better way & why this wouldn't work. Thanks!!